# The operation could not be performed because of one or more tree conflicts

Tags: xcode, github

xCode has problem with Github.
When I try to pull the warning pops up like below.
"The operation could not be performed because of one or more tree conflicts. The file Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist had a tree conflict."

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ git branch backup            # backup the branch for safety             

# keep the remote changes
$ git pull origin <branch> -s recursive -X theirs

# keep the local changes
$ git pull origin <branch> -s recursive -X ours
```